# message when leaving a datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagridview with a menustrip. I want to give the user a message that he has to save when he leaves the datagridview and made any changes in there. What i tried:

```
Private Sub DGV_validated(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DGV.validated
If DataSet1.table.GetChanges IsNot Nothing Then
MsgBox("You made changes please press the save button!")
End If
End Sub
```

I tried that with the leave, validated and lostfocus event but the msgbox pops up not until i am on another form after pressing something in the menustrip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made a forms project with a `DataGridView` on the form and put this in the code behind and it worked without issue:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.MouseLeave
    MsgBox("hi")
End Sub
```

Basically, after the cursor leaves the `DataGridView`, the `MsgBox` will pop up. Is that what you were looking for? This was done in Visual Studio 2010.